# MVC5 @Html.EditorFor: Second Attribute Problem

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a minor frustration with the @html.EditorFor in MVC5, in a "Create View"

Basically, I have a drop down that the user selects information from. On Change, the value of the drop down is passed (via javascript) to the relative @Html.EditorFor, to be saved in the table upon submission of the view.

This is my view code for the DropDown (The dropdown itself is populated by the index controller, and works perfectly)

```
@Html.DropDownList("testList", null, "Select Delivery Unit", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

This is my view code for the EditorFor:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeliveryUnitID, null, "myunit", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Although the JavaScript is working properly, I will include that code as well, just in case it's needed:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[name='testList']").change(function () {
            $("#myunit").val($(this).val());

        });
    });

</script>
```

The user selects an option from the "testlist" dropdown, and that value is passed to "myunit" with the javascript provided. That all works really well.  But, when I save the data. . . that field is always empty. It's not capturing the value.

I believe the issue is with the second attribute (null).

What do I need to change to make this work properly?

Update:  Here is the Create View Controller Code

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {

        List<SelectListItem> testList = db.ICS_Units.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.DeliveryUnitID.ToString(), Text = x.DeliveryUnit, Selected = false }).DistinctBy(p => p.Text).ToList();
        ViewBag.testList = new SelectList(testList, "Value", "Text");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: InternalOrders/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TransID,SuppliesID,OriginalDate,TransType,LastUpdatedBy,Contact,OpenClosed,CurrentStatus,CurrentStatusDate,RequsitionNumber,PONumber,DeliveryMonth,DeliveryYear,UnitsOrdered,Emergency,Comments,DeliveryUnitID")] ICS_Transactions iCS_Transactions)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ICS_Transactions.Add(iCS_Transactions);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(iCS_Transactions);
    }
```

Comment: You are forcing the field name of "myunit". When you "save the data" are you posting to a controller action with a model containing a property name of "myunit"?

Comment: Please add your controller code that saves the data.

Comment: @jcruz:  My concept was that "myunit" is the id?  So that the javascript knows where to find the location to place the value?  And yes, posting to a controller action, but the model does not have the property name of "myunit".  Myunit was supposed to simply be an ID.   I come from the old asp.net web forms world.  Where a text box can be given an ID and you can pass variables to it.  That is what I was trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Alexander.  I will add the controller code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are forcing a HtmlFieldName to your field editor changes the default markup and your posted data. Leave the field name alone and instead update your jquery to match the model field name:

```
$('#DeliveryUnitID').val($(this).val());
```